# HP ZR2740w does not work with MBP 2016 13"

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, displayport

It works with my 2011 MBP 17" but when I plug it into my new 2016 13" MBP it does not. I'm using the DisplayPort input for both. thunderbolt 1 out on the 17" and USB C out on the 13"

The cable is good, because I tested it with another monitor and the 13". I have also tested the monitor on a late 2012 iMac and it also works.

Could it be the DP standard? I'm going to try and track down a DVI cable and see if that makes a difference.